# Is there any HTML5 or Javascript based Wireframing tool which can work on iPad?

Tags: gui-design, wireframe, ipad, html5

I want to keep my ipad with me to show my ideas to client because laptop is heavy and I think iPad can do this.

Is there any HTML5 or Javascript based Wireframing tool which can work on iPad and can show the output on ipad?

I want click based facility too.

### Edit:

I need clickable hotspot to change pages by tapping on specific part of the page. It necessary to be a HTML

I'm looking for something like this https://cacoo.com/ but should work on iPad. this tool is based on Flash.

And I'm looking for a tool to make prototype for all type of websites and Webapps. not only for iPad/iPhone apps.

Comment: VNC back to your home machine with Balsamiq on it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use Keynote for iPad. In addition you can buy a wireframe toolkit for keynote.

[Wireframe Toolkit for Keynote](http://keynotekungfu.com/)

Answer (score 1):

There are some wireframing apps especially for the iPad.

Apps like [iMockups](http://www.endloop.ca/imockups/) for example. I'd actually consider getting an iPad just for apps like this. (Ideally get my work to pay for one for me, but that's unlikely!)

Comment: can me make online link of our mockup to share with client and developers?

Comment: accodrding to website "just export to PNG or Balsamiq BMML format" so i think online sharing is not possible in this

Answer (score 1):

[Evolus Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn) can export wireframes to HTML with links between pages to simulate interaction. There are [several templates that export to HTML](http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Downloads/Templates.aspx) (but you'll probably need to modify the CSS to suit the iPad screen size).

Comment: This free app is great for easy prototyping. You can even create your own widgets with some coding experience.

Answer (score 0):

What is 'click based facility' mean? Is are you referring to clickable prototypes? If so, I think most products will output HTML, so at least you could view it on the iPad.

I think keynote is a good suggestion.

I haven't tried it on the iPad, but, at least in theory, Google Docs should work. The drawing tools in there are getting pretty good. Not sure if they can make clickable prototypes.

All that said, I'm not sure you want 'clickable prototypes' unless you are actually prototyping an iPad app. The interactions with a touch tablet are quite a bit different than with a mobile device as they are with a desktop computer. Clickable prototypes should be confined to the particular device(s) you are targetting IMHO otherwise you run into the issue where people are looking at a prototype outside the context of the device (I run into that ALL the time where a UX team will prototype out mobile UIs via the desktop. What works and 'feels' right by clicking and navigating with a mouse quickly turns into mud when they actually get it onto the phone).

Comment: @DA - I added more clarification to my question

Comment: I guess my answer is still the same. If you are prototyping desktop apps, don't show them on an iPad. If you re designing iPad apps, don't show the prototype on a desktop computer. It all depends on your needs and your audience, of course, but in general, I try to get the clients/stakeholders to use the prototype in the exact same context as the end users will.